# Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync is not a function

Tags: google-maps, location, expo, jmapviewer

I just try to use expo-location and I found that error
Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync is not a function

this is my code

```
import * as Location from 'expo-location';

const setCurrentLocation = async() => {
        let { status } = await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();
        if (status !== 'granted') {
            setErrorMsg('Permission to access location was denied');
            return;
          }
          let location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({});
          setLocation(location);
            if (errorMsg) {
                setCheckText(errorMsg)
            } else if (location) {
                setCheckText(JSON.stringify(location))
            }  
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To display the coordinates -

1. Initialize your `state` like this

```js
import { useState } from "react";

.
.
.

const [location, setLocation] = useState(null);
```

2. Define `setCurrentLocation` function as shown

```js
const setCurrentLocation = async () => {
  let { status } = await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();

  if (status !== 'granted') {
    setErrorMsg('Permission to access location was denied');
    return;
  }

  let location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({});
  setLocation(location);
};
```

3. Then your `render` part will look something like this

```js
return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    {location ? <Text>latitude = {location.coords.latitude}</Text> : null}
    {location ? <Text>longitude = {location.coords.longitude}</Text> : null}
  </View>
);
```

[Working Example](https://snack.expo.io/@kartikeyvaish/location-example)

Comment: I try that and give me the same error 
promise rejection: TypeError: Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync is not a function.

Comment: Check the snack that I made and try to follow up with it. If you still couldn't find the solution then post your `App.js`. But first try to solve it on your own..It will help you

Comment: I changed it to requestPermissionsAsync  and it solved now but how can I treat with the location as I use JSON.stringify but still can't use CheckText.coords

Comment: Its good that you solved but you should know `"requestPermissionsAsync" is now deprecated.`

Comment: Check answer to see how to access the co-ordinates

Comment: TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'location.coords.latitude') I think I need to change the object by JSON.stringify to use it

Comment: Make sure you initialize the State like this - `const [location, setLocation] = React.useState(null);` also make the render same as mine

Comment: Check Snack and follow from there

Comment: Finally something that works...! Thank you @Kartikey